# List all instances of class created

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to see the list of all instances that have been created for a class (using `NSLog`).  Any idea?

Edit:  I meant to ask to see the list of current active instances of a class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520263/get-all-instances-of-a-class-in-objective-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125000/objective-c-how-can-i-get-class-instance-in-class-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just add pointers to those instances to a global collection. Then you can just refer to the collection when you want to find out details like that.

Comment: Chris: My bad, I was not asking the question correctly.  Please see my edited.  Any other suggestion?  Btw: I will accept yours as the answer if no one has the answer.  Since you did address the original.

Comment: How would you define "active instances"?

Comment: Say, I created an instant of MySpecialClass within an instant of MyCustomClass1 and from within an instant of MyCustomClass2, etc.  My goal was to find all instances of MySpecialClass that are active (that have not been nil-ed out).